# Optional prop/property in Flutter

Tags: flutter, react-native

I'm in `Flutter`, and I know something about `React Native`. In `React Native` I create optional props like this:

```
foo?: boolean;
```

How do I do the same thing in `Flutter`?

I looked [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/flutter-for/react-native-devs) and didn't find it.

Comment: It is just boolean? foo;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way to you reproduce optional props in Flutter is something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    final String myProperty; 
    final List<int> anotherProp;
    final String? nullSafetyProp; //can be optional
    late final String lateProp; // shold be initialized in Future. Before read the value
    
    MyClass({
       required this.myProperty,
       required this.anotherProp,
       this.nullSafetyProp, // optional property
       required this.lateProp
    });
}
```

- about keyword `final`:
  https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-
- about
  `nullsafety`: https://dart.dev/null-safety
- `late` variables: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables
- `late final` variables: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-final-variables